# issue with blocks and memory releases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
- (void) likeImage:(AHInstagramImageData *) image
            success:(void (^)(BOOL success))success
           failure:(void (^)(NSError* error, NSInteger statusCode))failure
{
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [AHInstagramSession session].accessToken, @"access_token",
                            nil];
    NSString *likeCommentPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"media/%@/likes", image.imageId];
    [self postPath:likeCommentPath parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response){
        if ([operation hasAcceptableStatusCode]) {
            [[LocalyticsSession sharedLocalyticsSession] tagEvent:@"Like"];

            [[AHFacebookSession session] postAction:@"like" forImageData:image];
            [[AHTwitterSession session] postAction:@"like" andObject:image];

            success(YES);


    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
         failure(error, operation.response.statusCode);
         NSLog(@"Failure on liking a photo %@", [error description]);
    }];
}
```

and it gives me the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like a memory problem. Check `success` block if it was actually set before you invoke it.

```
if (success)
{
    success(YES);
}
```

Comment: how can it be set before I invoke it?

Comment: What I mean the parameter you pass to `success:(void (^)(BOOL success))success`. If `success` is a NULL block your app will crash. I'm guessing that's what's happening because the top of your stack trace says `__block_invoke_0`